# python comparing list values to keys in list of dicts

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts a and a list b as shown below. len(b) will not always be 4. it may be 2 or 3. I compared values in b to keys in each dict in b. I obtained the result shown, which should rightly be of length b but the order is not as desired.

My 2 problems are:

1. The result is not printed in order. i.e. not depending on which value comes first in my list
2. Is there a better way of comparison? ( I am sure there is) because len(b) will not always be 4. It may be smaller.

Here is what I have

```
a = [{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 7, 3: 0}, {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 12, 3: 0}, {0: 5, 1: 0, 2: 8, 3: 0}]
b = [2, 0, 1, 3]
c = []
for i in a:
    x = []
    for k, v in i.items():
        if k == b[0]: 
           x.append(v)
        if k == b[1]:
            x.append(v)
        if k == b[2]:
            x.append(v)
        if k == b[3]:
            x.append(v)
    c.append(x)
print(c)
```

My result is

`[[0, 1, 7, 0], [0, 0, 12, 0], [5, 0, 8, 0]]`

If you notice, for `b = 2` i.e. `b[0]`, the result from `a[1`] is rightly 7 but it comes after 0 and 1 in my final result even though 2 is the first item in b.

Thank you

Comment: For what problem is it a solution? What is the intended meaning of this "result"? It's not clear what the actual question is.

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: if you copy my code as it is, it works. My problem is the order and the way I make comparisons

Comment: Please help me understand the down vote so I can improve. I am learning by practice and you guys have been helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
res = [[d[i] for i in b] for d in a]

print(res)

[[7, 0, 1, 0], [12, 0, 0, 0], [8, 5, 0, 0]]
```

To understand how this works, it sometimes helps to write out the full nested `for` loop:

```
res = []
for d in a:
    res_int = []
    for i in b:
        res_int.append(d[i])
    res.append(res_int)
```

A functional approach is also possible:

```
res = [list(map(d.get, b)) for d in a]
```

Comment: Yes I agree. I have been practicing that. Most of my practice comes with a lot of for loops and if statements. That is why I am trying to understand  shorter methods. Thank you for your response

Comment: Your last answer is really short and straight. Wish I can write all my codes that way. Getting down to understanding it.

Comment: very nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you do not iterate **with regards to b**. You iterate with regards to key order in dictionaries inside **a**. Thats why output elements are out of order.

For the correct solution, you should iterate with regards to b's items, like this:

```
a = [{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 7, 3: 0}, {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 12, 3: 0}, {0: 5, 1: 0, 2: 8, 3: 0}]
b = [2, 0, 1, 3]
c = []
for a_dict in a:
    x = []
    for b_element in b:
        if b_element in a_dict:
            x.append(a_dict[b_element])
            print("Appending %ss value %s to X! new X: %s" % (b_element, a_dict[b_element], str(x)))
    c.append(x)
print(c)
```

Prints:

```
Appending Key:2s Value:7 to X! new X: [7]
Appending Key:0s Value:0 to X! new X: [7, 0]
Appending Key:1s Value:1 to X! new X: [7, 0, 1]
Appending Key:3s Value:0 to X! new X: [7, 0, 1, 0]
Appending Key:2s Value:12 to X! new X: [12]
Appending Key:0s Value:0 to X! new X: [12, 0]
Appending Key:1s Value:0 to X! new X: [12, 0, 0]
Appending Key:3s Value:0 to X! new X: [12, 0, 0, 0]
Appending Key:2s Value:8 to X! new X: [8]
Appending Key:0s Value:5 to X! new X: [8, 5]
Appending Key:1s Value:0 to X! new X: [8, 5, 0]
Appending Key:3s Value:0 to X! new X: [8, 5, 0, 0]
[[7, 0, 1, 0], [12, 0, 0, 0], [8, 5, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: oh okay. so you iterate with regards to the variable that contains your desired output?

Comment: Yes. From your post, I understood that you want to order them with respect to `b`. So I tried to correct your code that way.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `operator.itemgetter` which provides a neat shorthand to retrieve multiple items in one go:

```
>>> a = [{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 7, 3: 0}, {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 12, 3: 0}, {0: 5, 1: 0, 2: 8, 3: 0}]
>>> b = [2, 0, 1, 3]
>>> 
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> get_b = itemgetter(*b)
```

Now for example:

```
>>> get_b(a[0])
(7, 0, 1, 0)
```

The result is a tuple, not a list. If that's ok you can make a list comprehension or use map:

```
>>> [get_b(d) for d in a]
[(7, 0, 1, 0), (12, 0, 0, 0), (8, 5, 0, 0)]
>>> list(map(get_b, a))
[(7, 0, 1, 0), (12, 0, 0, 0), (8, 5, 0, 0)]
```

If it must be lists, it's a bit more cumbersome:

```
>>> [list(get_b(d)) for d in a]
[[7, 0, 1, 0], [12, 0, 0, 0], [8, 5, 0, 0]]
>>> list(map(list, map(get_b, a)))
[[7, 0, 1, 0], [12, 0, 0, 0], [8, 5, 0, 0]]
```

On my system `itemgetter` appears to be a bit faster than one-by-one lookup even if we have to convert tuples to lists:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>>
>>> def multi_get(a, b):
...     get_b = itemgetter(*b)
...     return [[*get_b(d),] for d in a]
... 
>>> def multi_get_tuple(a, b):
...     get_b = itemgetter(*b)
...     return [get_b(d) for d in a]
... 
>>> timeit("multi_get_tuple(a, b)", globals=globals(), number=1000000)
0.9130640690000291
>>> timeit("multi_get(a, b)", globals=globals(), number=1000000)
1.0864301430010528
>>> timeit("[[d[i] for i in b] for d in a]", globals=globals(), number=1000000)
1.40757593699891
```